# Session variables in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, express-session

I am a web developer with a PHP background that moved recently to JS.

In PHP, we used to have the `$_SESSION` global variable which make your session variables accessible from any 'place' in your code (Great feature!).

Now, working with an ExpressJS application, I am using express-session package to create session variables.

The issue is that session variables in ExpressJS are NOT global, they are property of the request object (`req.session`). So they are only accessible in functions that have a req parameter (AKA middlewares and route functions).

The question is: Is it possible to make session variables in ExpressJS global ala PHP, so any 'helper' function can handle them?

Comment: You seem to have a misconception about the term 'global'. Neither in PHP nor elsewhere session variables are global because the global scope is accessible by _anyone_ whereas you want to restrict session variables to a single client. So the answer is that even if it was possible, you wouldn't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you should **not** do that. You can create globals by appending properties to the `global` object. For example: `global.someData = req.session.someData`, but the `global` object is similar to the `GLOBAL` from PHP.

In that case, especially if you have async functions, the variables of one request will mess up with the code running for another request (e.g. Alice would get the Bob's variables).

The good practice is to pass the `req.session` object wherever that is needed and access it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CLS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/continuation-local-storage) (Continuation-local-storage) to achieve this. 
All you have to do is create a namespace and bind it to each request.

Now, add the below code to your server.js where you initialize your server

```
//server.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var createNameSpace = require('continuation-local-storage').createNamespace;
var myNameSpace = createNameSpace('myNameSpace');

// Assign your sessionVariable to each request as 'sessionId'
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    myNameSpace.run(function() {
        myNameSpace.set('sessionId', sessionVariable);
        next();
    });
});
```

Add the following code anywhere in you application to access your sessionVariable

```
var getNamespace = require('continuation-local-storage').getNamespace;
var myNameSpace = getNamespace('myNameSpace');
var sessionId = myNameSpace.get('sessionId'); // access your sessionId (sessionVariable)
```

Note that using CLS can be tricky sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Once your session variable is setup (either on your login function or wherever you are setting it up) it is then a global variable on your index.js file.

I setup my session like so:

```
var students = {Id: result[key].Id,Username: result[key].Username,Email: result[key].Email,Phone: result[key].Phone,First_Name: result[key].First_Name,Surname: result[key].Surname,RoleName: result[key].RoleName, Company: result[key].CompanyName };

Users.push(students);
req.session.user = students;
```

You can access the stored session by setting up a var like the below:

```
var session = req.session.user
```

This will set the session to a session variable where you need it inside your function.
Then when you render a page you just need to add the session to that render and you will have access to it on that page.

```
res.render('/', { title: 'Hello World', session: session});
```